# What is the connection between watts and electron volts?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, dimensional-analysis, units, power

I saw that $1$ w/s is equivalent to $6.2 \times 10^{18}$ eV. But if that was true $1$ w/s or less could fully ionize any atom is that true?

Comment: I assume you mean watt-seconds, not watts/second?

Comment: Well yes, but only if you could direct that 1 joule of energy onto a single atom, and how do you plan to do that?

Comment: *I saw that $1$ w/s is equivalent to $6.2 \times 10^{18}$ eV.* If you really saw that, you should ignore the source. It isn’t correct. Watts per second are not a unit of energy.

Answer (score 1):

The statement "1 watt per second is equivalent to 6.2×10^18 electronvolts" is incorrect.

Watts and electronvolts are different units and cannot be directly compared in this way. Watts are a unit of power, which is the rate at which energy is transferred or used, while electronvolts are a unit of energy.

To fully ionize an atom, enough energy must be provided to remove all of its electrons. The amount of energy required to fully ionize an atom depends on its atomic number and electron configuration. For example, the ionization energy of hydrogen is about 13.6 electronvolts, while the ionization energy of uranium is about 6 million electronvolts.

Therefore, 1 watt per second or less cannot fully ionize any atom. The amount of energy required to fully ionize an atom is much larger than the energy produced by 1 watt per second.

Answer (score 0):

The electron volt is a unit of energy, equivalent to approximately $1.6022\times10^{-19}\ {\rm J}$. It's the energy required to move a particle carrying the elementary charge through a potential difference of 1 V.

Thus 1 J is approximately $6.2414\times10^{18}\ {\rm eV}$ and 1 W is approximately $6.2414\times10^{18}\ {\rm eV/s}$.

The units W/s (watts per second) represent a rate of change of power, not unheard of but not something that is used particularly often in physics.

Answer (score 0):

The question arises from the mixing of quantities close to the macroscopic world with microscopic quantities. Your energy (1 W.s = $6.2 \times 10^{18} eV$ in the usual electrical context comes precisely from a large amount of quasi-ionized moving charges. You can see that using this energy to ionize charges is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

The first ionization energies for various atoms shown here: https://www.britannica.com/science/ionization-energy. Note they
range between 5 eV and 25 eV. So yes, 1 watt second (1 Joule) of energy could cause ionization. The problem is, as @John Rennie commented, you would need to be able to direct that energy at a single atom.

Hope this helps